# Replace Not Correctly Removing for Object Variable Type

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove the ":30" portion of values in my `First` variable. The `First` variable data type is object.

Here are a few examples of of the `First` variable, and the counts, ignore the counts:

```
11a       211
7p        178
4p        127
2:30p     112
11:30a    108
1p        107
12p       105
9a        100
10p        85
2p         24
10:30a     12
6p          5
9:30a       2
9p          2
12:30a      2
8p          2
```

I wrote the following code which runs without any errors; however, when I run the value counts, it still shows times with a ":30". The `NewFirst` variable dataype is int64.Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    bad_chars = ":30"
DF["NewFirst"] = DF.First.replace(bad_chars,'')
DF["NewFirst"].value_counts()
```

The desired output would have the `NewFirst` values like:

```
11a       211
7p        178
4p        127
2p        112
11a       108
1p        107
12p       105
9a        100
10p        85
2p         24
10a        12
6p          5
9a          2
9p          2
12a        2
8p          2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping over the characters in `bad_chars`. That will remove all `3` and `0` characters, so `10p` will become `1p`, and `3a` will become `a`.

You should just replace the whole `bad_chars` string, with no loop.

You also need to use the `.str` accessor.

```
DF["NewFirst"] = DF["First"].str.replace(bad_chars,'')
```

Comment: Thanks but this code still is not changing the output, the NewFirst variable still contains values that have ":30". I also updated my post to reflect your code.

Comment: Don't remove the original code, now my answer doesn't make any sense because it refers to something that no longer appears in the question.

Comment: I think you need `.str`, I've upated the answer.